# Go install: Go local import "../app/lib" in non-local package

Tags: go, intellij-idea, import

The code works with `go build main.go` and will run the application. However, `go install` will throw an error. What gives?

Project structure:

```
app/
    main.go
    lib/
        StockMarketController.go
        GetStockMarketData.go
```

In my `main.go`, the two other .go files are imported as such:

```
import (
    Lib "../stockmarket-service/lib"
)
```

And called as such:

```
Lib.SomeFunction()
```

And it works!

Why does it fail with `go install`? How do I fix my import of them?

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and building it in there with `go build`, the directory is `~./IdeaProjects/app`, could this be the issue?

Comment: Go imports are relative to GOPATH, never use relative import paths.

Comment: Ok. How would I solve it with this setup, then?

Comment: Follow the instructions at [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)